# How to check a Mobile URL exists in c#

Tags: c#, validation, url

I'm trying to identify if sites have a mobile version - as in m.bbc.co.uk.

Entering it into a browser works fine, but any method of checking with HTTPwebrequests all fail as you cannot use: `Http://m.bbc.co.uk` and so I cannot see how I can check.

Does anyone know how to make a web request for a m.*** site??

Comment: Why does it fail or rather what qualifies as failing?

Comment: There's no reason it should be failing specifically for 'm' subdomains on a domain but succeed for other domains, post your code.

Comment: Also, there's no guarantee that a mobile site will be at m.*, where does this assumption comes from?